# Windows batch For Loop dropping empty strings to the end

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have this following code.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set holdingline=,Measure,,+ X,,,0,0
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 delims=," %%a IN ("%holdingline%") DO (
    echo %%a
    echo %%b
    echo %%c
    echo %%d
    echo %%e
    echo %%f
    echo %%g
    echo %%h
    echo %holdingline%
)
pause
```

Output displayed is as below:

```
Measure
+ X
0
0
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
,Measure,,+ X,,,0,0
```

The empty strings are pushed to the end and I wonder why. I am expecting them in order, say something like:

```
ECHO is off.
Measure
ECHO is off.
+ X
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
0
0
,Measure,,+ X,,,0,0
```

This would enable me to assign them to the correct variables. I tried searching but did not find much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set holdingline=,Measure,,+ X,,,0,0
FOR /F "tokens=1-8 delims=," %%a IN (""%holdingline:,=","%"") DO (
    ECHO(%%~a
    ECHO(%%~b
    ECHO(%%~c
    ECHO(%%~d
    ECHO(%%~e
    ECHO(%%~f
    ECHO(%%~g
    ECHO(%%~h
    echo %holdingline%
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should solve your problem

---

To process a file, producing a new file

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%x IN (q29639243.txt) DO (
 set "holdingline=%%x"
 CALL :process
)
)>u:\new.txt

GOTO :EOF

:process
FOR /F "tokens=1-8 delims=," %%a IN (""%holdingline:,=","%"") DO (
    ECHO(%%~a
    ECHO(%%~b
    ECHO(%%~c
    ECHO(%%~d
    ECHO(%%~e
    ECHO(%%~f
    ECHO(%%~g
    ECHO(%%~h
    echo %holdingline%
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q29639243.txt` containing similar data for my testing.
Produces u:\new.txt

Comment: Can the same be done using a file. I mean instead of using set command to enter value holdingline is there a way to read the file record into holdingline variable and do the same task?

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want it to:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set holdingline=,Measure,,+ X,,,0,0
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 delims=," %%a IN ("%holdingline:,,=, ,%") DO (
    echo %%a
    echo %%b
    echo %%c
    echo %%d
    echo %%e
    echo %%f
    echo %%g
    echo %%h
    echo %holdingline%
)
pause
```

Replacing `,,` with `, ,` will cause it to set the middle variables to  (space) and hence treat them like nothing. If you don't have anything between two `,` it will skip them and hence only 4 variables exist, leaving `e-h` blank

Comment: Thanks. Your solution gets me closer. But it still doesn't treat the first null at the begining of the string and the 2 consecutive nulls as expected.